# Caching in mmap

Tags: c++, caching, mmap

I am using mmap call to read from a very big file using simple pointer arithmetic in C++. The problem is that when I read small chunks of data (in the order of KBs) multiple times, each read take the same amount of time as the previous one. How can I know if the disk is being accessed to fulfill my request or whether the request is being fulfilled from main memory (page cache) in calls after the first one.

Comment: Speed! I want to know why the subsequent calls are no faster than the first one when I expect them to be fulfilled from cache rather than through a disk access.

Comment: did you also profile the time it took for the mmap call? It is possible that it already cached the first page when you invoked mmap. All modern major desktop operating systems will cache, since going out to disk is so expensive, although if you have a very weird access pattern, you may be forcing cache misses on every single access (is your access pattern sequential?).

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan, I think you make a very good point, now all I need is a way to flush my cache under linux to ensure that the first call is being fulfilled from disk. My access pattern is not strictly sequential, but it can benefit from locality in many cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the following: both reads were being performed from cache. I guess caching starts when the file is opened or mmapped, before asking for the data. To verify this, I issued:

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

which flushes out the cache, then, if I run two iterations for getting the same data, the first run is (in my case) 10 times slower than the second.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the best cache performance if you exploit [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). That is to say that if you access variables that are close together in memory (e.g. stepping by one in increasing order through the variables) and you perform these accesses close in time (i.e. not performing many other memory accesses between reading these elements), then you will get the best cache performance. If each read is taking roughly the same amount of time, then it is very likely being cached; if things are not being served from cache, that is usually indicated by several fast reads (cache hits) followed by a spike (cache miss) followed by more fast reads. On almost all systems, a cache miss causes a chunk in which the data resides to be loaded into the cache, so if you access nearby variables (which are in the same chunk) they will be in the cache.